# Prepopulate field in a Facebook Registration Plugin

Tags: facebook, field, registration

I want to prepopulate the phone number field in a Facebook Registration Plugin, with the international prefix.

I tried with: value="+44" and "value" : "+44"

```
<fb:registration redirect-uri="" 
 fields='[
   {"name":"name"},
   {"name":"number","description":"Phone number","type":"text", value="+44"},
]' 
 onvalidate="validate"></fb:registration>
```

But it doesn't work, how can fix it out?

Comment: There’s nothing in the docs that suggests that this would be possible. A `default` only exists for select field and checkboxes.

Comment: Isn't possible? Are you sure?